# Connect Yii2 app to My sql cluster

Tags: yii2, mysql-cluster

Does it makes any different if I was using mysql db and now I want to use Mysql cluster on my server. How will this affect my yii2 application ?? do I have to make any changes to db connection or just connect to any node ? does this affect Active Queries ?? Does it affect the active model relations ??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to carefully read [Known Limitations of NDB Cluster](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-cluster-limitations.html) section in the MySQL docs.

Most important parts are:

- column width limit for indexation,
- TEXT and BLOB cannot be indexed,
- BIT column cannot be a primary key, unique key, or index, nor can it be part of a composite primary key, unique key, or index,
- you cannot have table with AUTO_INCREMENT column and no explicit primary key,
- only READ COMMITTED transaction isolation level,
- foreign keys are supported only in NDB Cluster 7.3 and later.

AR implementation in Yii 2 should be basically fine. You connect in the same way as usual.

Comment: Thank you so much.. by reading the above points. It seems that it's not a right to choice to use. I'm going to just configure mysql Master Master Replication between two servers.